# How can I darken everything displayed in a single NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit

**Background:** My application has a main window which contains a few smaller `NSView` objects, each of which contains several different controls, labels, images, etc. One of these views (and everything it contains) is disabled in response to a given flag. When the flag is set, I automatically disable and grey-out all of the controls embedded within that `NSView`.

**Question:** I would like to know how to *darken* the disabled `NSView`. The effect I am looking for would be something like drawing a 50% transparent black box on top of the disabled `NSView`. The background and all of the controls would still be visible, but the colors would be a darker shade. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoreAnimation in 10.5 should provide an easy way to put a translucent layer above a view. You can create a black layer in front of the view, with the opacity at 0%. When you want to darken the view, set the opacity of the black layer to 50%, and the view will be darkened smoothly.

Comment: Good idea; Thank you! I hadn't considered using CoreAnimation.

Comment: Hi, I have same kind of requirement for NSDrawer ContentView. please provide me some code to put translucent layer above a NSDrawer ContentView. Thanks