# Graying out an NSWindow's content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I have an `NSWindow` with 2 `NSViews` (an `NSSplitView` and a custom `NSView`). Accessing the data to populate these views can take some time. During this period, I'd like to gray out the content of these views.

My first approach was to have a black third `NSView` that covered the other 2 and achieve the graying out effect by changing its alpha value. However I've since learned having a hierarchy with sibling views is undefined.

What is the best approach here?

- Cache the `NSBitmapImageRep` of the 2 views, then replace them with the 3rd view, using the cached image(s) as background
- Set the alpha value for each view separately (still not quite sure how to get the black background for the graying effect)
- Something I haven't considered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a child window. Set its content view to a plain black view (hopefully with status and progress information in subviews), and its alpha value to the desired fade-out, and add it as a child window of the window whose content you want to fade out.

Comment: Wow. I had never looked into windows being children of windows. That's perfect, thanks!

Comment: A child window is a bit of overkill for this situation.  Child windows  are meant for things like NSDrawers or palettes that attach to a window's edges.

I'd go with NSD's suggestion below, and implement a disabled state in your views so they draw differently when inactive.  That's the way the Appkit handles disabled controls.

Comment: well I also want to overlay a progress bar, so this solution works a bit better in that case

Comment: Adding a disabled state is a good idea, but they're not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I'd teach the views how to draw themselves in a disabled state, but there are other suggestions here:

[How can I darken everything displayed in a single NSView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466249/how-can-i-darken-everything-displayed-in-a-single-nsview)