# NSView overlay passes mouse events to underlying subviews?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a loading overlay which is supposed to block all the AppKit Controls off untill loading is done. However the view seems to be passing all the mouse events to the underlying layers. How to disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I suggest using a child window instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656049/graying-out-an-nswindows-content)